# What does the TortoiseHG option to show files "Changed by this Commit" actually do?

Tags: tortoisehg

In TortoiseHG Workbench you get an extra dropdown menu when you view a merge commit. The dropdown options are:

[image]

- Changed by This Commit
- Compare to 1st Parent
- Compare to 2nd Parent

**But what does the "Changed by This Commit" option actually mean?**

At first I expected it to show only files which actually had a difference introduced by the merge commit itself. For instance, a file with a conflict which needed some editing to resolve. But this is clearly not correct, lots of other files are included.

Second thought was that it might show a union of the other two choices -- but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

I looked in [the THG documentation](http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workbench.html) but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Need more info. Like you said, "only files which actually had a difference introduced by the merge commit itself", that is how it works to me.

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski well, it includes files which were not manually edited. I'm not sure what else to say... there is no apparent pattern that I can figure out as to why these other files are included.